# View Windows shares from Mac OS X

Tags: windows, macos, network-shares, finder

I have multiple Windows XP/7 computers with shared folders. What I want is to be able to see those shared folders in Finder of Mac OS X.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly easy to set up. Create a share on your Windows machine, and from the Mac, click Go > Server > and type in the name (or IP address) of the Windows box (using `smb://` prefix).

You should be prompted with a screen showing the shares and a prompt for username and password. I forget the exact order.

See [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1568) for more info.

EDIT: To remember your shared connection, go to `System Preferences` > `Accounts` > your account > `Login Items` and add the shared volume using the dialogs there. More info [here](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20030625104447795).

Comment: Potter: yep, this one worked for me. One last question before I accept your answer - how to make it consistantly connect to this server at startup? For some reason in my office Mac OS locating windows shares automatically even without adding Server...

Comment: I've modified my original answer with how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in OS 10.5 or later, you should be able to see the Windows machines in a regular Finder window by clicking on "Shared" in the left nav.

If you don't see the computers at all, take a look at Windows Firewall.  By default, it blocks SMB file sharing from the Windows box, but won't stop the Windows box from mounting a drive on another machine.  Turn it off completely and try again.  If it works, you found your problem.

Comment: Turn off your firewall complete? This is not good advice.

Comment: It is perfectly reasonable trouble-shooting measure.

Comment: There is no Shared folder there. Windows firewall is off and I'm able to connect to that shared resource from other Windows 7 PC. Other ideas please... I suspect it has something to do with Windows 7.